# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' on Azure SQL with Active Directory Admin via SSMS

Tags: ssms, azure-sql

When I attempt to connect to an Azure SQL Server via SQL Server Management Studio using the "Active Directory - Universal with MFA support" method with an account that is configured as the Active Directory Admin, the following error message is shown:

[image: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)].

The state value given under "Show technical details" is "State: 1", but [the real state obtained via Audit Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631093/62838) is 132, indicating ["AAD Failure"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-2017).

The user I'm logging in with is in an Azure AD group that's definitely set as the Active Directory Admin in the portal. Checking with the other admin login created when the server was initialized, I can see that the group is indeed enabled in the `master` database.

What's the reason for this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the reason seems to have been that the user is associated with multiple Azure ADs. I had to specify the Azure AD of the Azure SQL Server using the "Options >>" button:

[image: AD domain name or tenant ID option]